# Determine the total profit made on the sale of cupcakes, as a formula based on sale price and number sold.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Fred is making cupcakes for a charity sale. The ingredients cost 15p per cake. Suppose that each cake is sold for £ and that Fred sells  cakes.

**a) Write down a formula for the total profit £ Fred makes, in terms of  and .**

$P = (C - 0.15)n$

90 people will attend the charity sale. If Fred charges nothing at all for his cakes, 75 people will take a cake (and Fred will make no money). For each pound above zero Fred charges per cake, 20 fewer people will buy a cake.

**b) Explain why  = −20 + 75**

If C=0, n = 75
If C=1, n = 75 - 20
=> n = 75 - 20C, i.e. n = -20C + 75

Is that enough of an explanation, doesn't seem adequate?

**c) Show that $ = −20^2 + 78 − 11.25$**

$P = (C - 0.15)n\\
=> P = (C - 0.15)(-20C + 75)\\
=>  = −20^2 + 75 +3C − 11.25\\
=>  = −20^2 + 78 − 11.25
$

Seemed a bit simple, have I missed a more elegant solution?

**d) By expanding $( − 1.95)^2$, find a number  such that $ = −20( − 1.95)^2 + k$**

$( − 1.95)^2 = C^2 - 3.9C + 3.8025\\
=>  = −20(C^2 - 3.9C + 3.8025) + k\\
=>  = −20C^2 + 78C - 76.05 + k$

From part (d) 
$-11.25 = -76.05 + k\\
=> k = 64.8$

**e) What price should Fred charge for each cupcake if he wishes to raise the most money
possible for charity? Explain your answer.**

This should be the maximum value of $ = −20^2 + 78 − 11.25$

Using the maximum value of a quadratic equation max = c - (b2 / 4a):

$=> max = -11.25 - (78^2 / 4(-20))\\
=> max = 64.80$

$=> −20^2 + 78 − 11.25 = 64.80\\
=> −20^2 + 78 − 76.05 = 0
$

Using Quadratic Formula: C = 1.95

**So Fred should charge £1.95 to raise the most money for charity.**

Is there a quicker, more elegant, method to come to this conclusion (if it's correct ofc)?

Comment: Is it OK to use calculus? If so there's a faster way.

Comment: @coffeemath Precalculus at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

Part e follows immediately from part d since you have gotten the quadratic into vertex form with vertex at $C=1.95$, which must correspond with the max profit.